# Django popup error message

Tags: django, error-handling, django-forms

I am new to Django. I have a simple project where user can register and sign in. When user puts wrong username or password Django raises an error message. Like[image]

As you see it looks terrible. Is there any way to get popup error message in Django. I have searched for a long time and could not fine anything. I want something like that for login:
[image]

I am using Django django.contrib.auth.views.login for login.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Django doesn't help you with your front end designs

Comment: The second image that you attached is browser's error message (not the html/css/js), because email field was marked as `email`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using

```
{{ form.as_ul }}
```